# Difference between SharePoint Modern Search Experience and Microsoft Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

It's very confusing to understand about Search options around O365 and SharePoint online. [Modern Search Vs Microsoft Search](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265574/modern-search-vs-microsoft-search) 
Is

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint in Microsoft 365 has both a classic and a modern search experience. Microsoft Search in SharePoint is the modern search experience. Both search experiences use the same search index to find results. Let's say when you use the search box on the top bar in your SharePoint Modern site, that is using Microsoft search.

More information about [the differences between the classic and modern search experiences in SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/differences-classic-modern-search)

[Overview of Microsoft Search](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/overview-microsoft-search)